# Number of Ordered Trees of given degree sequence

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, reference-request

Is there any result known about counting the number of (unlabeled) ordered trees which follow a given unordered degree sequence?

Here an ordered tree is understood as a rooted tree in which the order of the subtrees is significant.

Comment: Ordered in what sense?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.03.18

Comment: @Gerhard Paseman An ordered tree is a rooted tree in which the order of the subtrees is significant.

Comment: And how is the degree sequence given? is it ordered as well?  Or is it just a multiset?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.03.18

Comment: @Gerhard Paseman sorry for the unclear specification: The degree sequence is ordered as well


Comment: so would degree sequence 2,1,3,4,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 mean the root has two children, the one on the left is a leaf and the one on the right has two children , one with 3 leaves on it and one with 4? That would uniquely specify the tree so it must not be that. Can you give an example?

Comment: the question is not clear at all. could you please give an example of a degree sequence, and preferably (following Aaron's comment) of a case when the degree sequence does not define a unique tree?

Comment: @marc: Please define precisely the notion of ordered tree and ordered degree sequence (as I don't understand it) or give a reference to it. Thanks.

Comment: OK so I suppose a path of 5 vertices directed away from an end vertex has degrees 1,1,1,1,0 (counting number of children) but directed from an internal vertex 2,1,1,0,0. If that is correct then *sequence of outdegrees* would have been clearer to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is Theorem 6.4 of  http://people.brandeis.edu/~gessel/homepage/papers/enum.pdf what you want?

Answer (score 0):

See Theorem 4.3 on page 12 [here](http://www.math-inf.uni-greifswald.de/mathe/images/Wandt/preprints/cieslik-countrees.pdf).

Comment: @GH Thank you for your answer. But this formula counts the number of labeled trees, whereas ordered trees are considered unlabeled. 